# Algorithm to convert std::stack to std::string in C++ STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++17, c++14

In below C++ program I'm deleting a previous character considering '#' as a backspace character. I have used stack to build the string. Is there any C++ STL algorithm, which can help me to covert the std::stack to std::string. Any alternative to the code with 'while' loop.

```
string buildString(string s) {
    stack<char> st;
    for(auto a : s) {
        if(a != '#') {
            st.push(a);
        } 
        else if(st.size()){
            st.pop();
        }
    }

    string result;
    while(st.size()) {
        result += st.top();
        st.pop();
    }

    reverse(begin(result), end(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Concerning _I have used stack to build the string._ Why? Are you aware of `std::string::push_back()`/`std::string::pop_back()`? Alternatively, you could change `s` in-place e.g. using `std::string::find()`/`std::string::erase()`.

Comment: You chose the wrong structure. A stack is not a sequence.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat : I was not aware of std::string::push_back()/std::string::pop_back(). Thank you so much for suggesting this.

Comment: @BharatPawar please include only the tags of the c++ version that you're using!

Comment: @codeline : sure! I will do that

Answer (score 0):

> I'm deleting a previous character considering '#' as a backspace character. I have used stack to build the string.

You could do this without additional space like `std::stack`:

```cpp
std::string buildString(const std::string& s) {
  std::string result;
    for(auto a : s) {
        if(a != '#') {
            result += a;
        } 
        else if(result.size()){
            result.pop_back();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```